# The need to sign a java desktop application

Tags: java, security, signing

I provide a java based editor to in internal network of xml editors.  Initially it was a plugin, changed to an Applet using jnlp to launch 6 years ago. With the eminent demise of web start I am changing the framework to a desktop Application. The Applet is signed and timestamped as required by all browsers. Once I transition to an installed java application I question whether I need to sign the application jars? The certificate is not cheap and the signing of 30+ jars takes a lot of time.  The editor is used on Macs, Windoze and Linux systems. Do I still have to sign it to get it to run? If not what is the downside of not signing, vs the upside to signing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desktop java applications **don't** validate jar signatures. So there is absolutely no benefit to continue signing your jars. Applets are dead (and so is the "sandbox" security model).

Comment: Well thats pretty simple, though it seems odd considering how many hoops we had to jump to get an applet running.  Changing to an application and all security goes out the window? Is there any way to force the JRE to verify signatures as web start does?

Comment: No. That is something you could do by writing your own class loader; for the extra benefit of nothing and the added cost of building, maintaining and supporting it yourself.